# exploding dictionary across rows, maintaining other column - python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, explode

I have a list of proteins (primaryAccession) and information about them that I have parsed from UnitProtKB. I scraped the information in JSON format, and I am trying to figure out how to write a loop that will separate the data into different columns. Currently my data looks like this:

| primaryAccession | uniProtKBCrossReferences |
| --- | --- |
| Q14457 | {'database': 'Reactome', 'id': 'R-HSA-1632852', 'properties': [{'key': 'PathwayName', 'value': 'Macroautophagy'}]}, {'database': 'Reactome', 'id': 'R-HSA-5689880', 'properties': [{'key': 'PathwayName', 'value': 'Ub-specific processing proteases'}]} |
| Q08380 | {'database': 'ProteomicsDB', 'id': '59999', 'properties': [{'key': 'Description', 'value': '-'}]}, {'database': 'Antibodypedia', 'id': '4116', 'properties': [{'key': 'antibodies', 'value': '1663 antibodies from 47 providers'}]} |

and I want it to look like this:

| primaryAccession | database | id | properties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q14457 | Reactome | R-HSA-1632852 | [{'key': 'PathwayName', 'value': 'Macroautophagy'}] |
| Q14557 | Reactome | R-HSA-5689880 | [{'key': 'PathwayName', 'value': 'Ub-specific processing proteases'}]} |
| Q08380 | ProteomicsDB | 59999 | [{'key': 'Description', 'value': '-'}] |
| Q08380 | Antibodypedia | 4116 | [{'key': 'antibodies', 'value': '1663 antibodies from 47 providers'}]} |

I have used this function (dict_list_to_df below) to split the 'unitProtKBCrossReferences' column, but it drops the primaryAccession column and I don't know how to add it back so that I can know which protein the information is referring to. How can I do this so that while I explode the 'uniProtKBCrossReferences' column, I can still keep the protein IDs (primaryAccession)?

```
def dict_list_to_df(df, col):
    """Return a Pandas dataframe based on a column that contains a list of JSON objects or dictionaries.
    Args:
        df (Pandas dataframe): The dataframe to be flattened.
        col (str): The name of the column that contains the JSON objects or dictionaries.
    Returns:
        Pandas dataframe: A new dataframe with the JSON objects or dictionaries expanded into columns.
    """

    rows = []
    for index, row in df[col].items():
        for item in row:
            rows.append(item)
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    return df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) the list of dicts then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) it to construct a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) :

```
from ast import literal_eval

df["uniProtKBCrossReferences"] = df["uniProtKBCrossReferences"].apply(literal_eval)
​
s = df["uniProtKBCrossReferences"].explode()

out = df[["primaryAccession"]].join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index))
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

  primaryAccession       database             id                                                             properties
0           Q14457       Reactome  R-HSA-1632852                    [{'key': 'PathwayName', 'value': 'Macroautophagy'}]
0           Q14457       Reactome  R-HSA-5689880  [{'key': 'PathwayName', 'value': 'Ub-specific processing proteases'}]
1           Q08380   ProteomicsDB          59999                                 [{'key': 'Description', 'value': '-'}]
1           Q08380  Antibodypedia           4116  [{'key': 'antibodies', 'value': '1663 antibodies from 47 providers'}]
```

Comment: Thank you, when I run this I get an error:

`ValueError: malformed node or string: [{'database': 'EMBL', 'id': 'AF077301', 'properties': [{'key': 'ProteinId', 'value': 'AAC68653.1'}, {'key': 'Status', 'value': '-'}, {'key': 'MoleculeType', 'value': 'mRNA'}]}, {'database': 'EMBL', 'id': 'AF139131', 'properties': [{'key': 'ProteinId', 'value': 'AAD27650.1'}, {'key': 'Status', 'value': '-'}, {'key': 'MoleculeType', 'value': 'mRNA'}]}, ..`

with this line: id_list["uniProtKBCrossReferences"] = id_list["uniProtKBCrossReferences"].apply(literal_eval)

Comment: Can you include this row to your question by adding it to your example/input ?